# How to pause and resume audio recording using AVAudioRecorder

Tags: iphone, objective-c, avaudiorecorder, recording

I need to pause and then resume an audio recording, I'm using AVAudioRecorder for my recording sessions...
Anyone knows how to do this?
Any help will be higly appreciated!
Thanks a lot
Peace
Massy

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After initializing and creating an object of `AVAudioRecorder`, lets say `AVAudioRecorder *recorder`, simply call `[recorder record]` to record and `[recorder pause]` to pause.

If you are calling record and pause in separate method e.g. on click of different buttons then you need to make `recorder` a class level variable.

Answer (score 1):

To pause the recording, use the following methods on `AVAudioRecorder`:

```
- (void)pause
```

and to resume, use:

```
- (BOOL)record
```

It's all [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioRecorder_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html) in the docs...